# C++ How to use functions from a cpp file in a header file

Tags: c++, sieve

I have a class in a header file called bitarray.h and a corresponding bitarray.cpp and I also have a sieve.h. The sieve.h and bitarray.cpp #includes the bitarray.h and sieve.h only has a function void Sieve(BitArray a). I would like to call Set() and Unset() which are declared in bitarray.h and defined in bitarray.cpp from the Sieve function but it will not let me. How do I fix this.

```
    //sieve.h
    #include "bitarray.h"
    #include <cmath>

    using namespace std;

    void Sieve(BitArray a)
    {
   //initialize all to 1
   for (int i = 0; i < (a.arraySize*a.unsChar*8); i++)
   {
    a.Set(i);
   }

   //unset 0 and 1 becasue they are never prime
   a.Unset(0);
   a.Unset(1);
   //leave 2 as a 1
       /*for (int i = 2; i < (a.arraySize*a.unsChar*8); i++)
    a.Unset(2*i);*/
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those functions, unless declared in the `bitarray.h` header, are local to the `bitarray.cpp`. If you want access to them in `sieve.h`, declare them in the `bitarray.h` header, or in another file accessible by `sieve.cpp`/`sieve.h`.

```
// bitarray.h
class BitArray
{
public:
  void Set(); // Example.
  void Unset(); // Example.
};

// sieve.h
#include bitarray.h
void Sieve(BitArray a)
{
  a.Set();
  a.Unset();
}
```

**EDIT:**

I'm pretty certain that the issue you're having, is that you're not seeing changes to your `BitArray` object because you're *passing a copy of the original*. Any changes you make to it in the `Sieve()` function won't be reflected in the original object.

Try passing the `BitArray` object by reference:

```
void Sieve(BitArray& a)
{
  ...
```

Comment: there is no sieve.cpp

Comment: He meant `sieve.h` :)

Comment: Whatever file includes `bitarray.h`.

Comment: I don't think Sieve is a class, merely a function

Comment: Sieve is not a class but BitArray is

Comment: that is what mine looks like and set and unset are defines in BitArray.cpp so they cannot be called from sieve.h. If I define set and unset in bitaray.h will that fix the problem?

Comment: set and unset are declared in bitarray.h as public member data

Comment: I understand now, that is what I meant to say. They are declared in bitarray.h and defined in bitarray.cpp yet I cannot access them in sieve.cpp

Comment: When you include `bitarray.h` you have access to the _declaration_ of those methods. The linking phase will link these to the _definitions_ in `bitarray.cpp` file. If what you have is the same as what I've posted - there is something else wrong. Do you have any errors? Show us the contents of `bitarray.h` and `bitarray.cpp`

Comment: no errors but when I call set or unset they do not do anything

Comment: should sieve be declared as friend function in bitarray.h?

Comment: You need to post more code, and you expected input and output, because what sounded like a problem in your original question isn't actually the problem you're having.

Comment: I added the sieve file, does that help?

Comment: it is not complete yet

Comment: Yeah I think I know what your issue is, check my edits.